# Convert single recursive call algorithm to a branching, multiple recursive call algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

> Write a recursive function `longest_word(my_list)` that takes a list of
>   words (each in the form of a string) and returns the longest word in
>   the list, using (at most) a single recursive function call from each
>   function call. On an empty list, your function should return None.

> Now see if you can rewrite the same function `longest_word(my_list)`
>   using multiple recursive function calls instead.

I tried the first problem which is quite easy to do. However I wonder how to convert the single to multiple recursive calls. In addition to the correct return output, the multiple recursive function must be invoked the correct number of times, which means the correct running logic corresponding to multiple recursive calls instead of single ones, even if their output results are essentially the same.

```
# First sample solution for single recursive calls
def longest_word(my_list):
    if not my_list:
        return None
    elif len(my_list) == 1:
        return my_list[0]
    else:
        l_word = longest_word(my_list[1:])
        if len(my_list[0]) > len(l_word):
            return my_list[0]
        else:
            return l_word
```

```
# Second sample solution for single recursive calls
def longest_word(my_list):
    l_word = _longest_word(my_list,'')
    if l_word == '':
        return None
    return l_word

def _longest_word(my_list, l_word):
    if not my_list:
        return l_word
    elif len(my_list[0]) > len(l_word):
        return _longest_word(my_list[1:], my_list[0])
    else:
        return _longest_word(my_list[1:], l_word)
```

You can modify the current two solutions for single recursive calls function to get multiple recursive calls function.

This question requires to split the list into two halves to have them run simultaneously rather than having one running all the way through to the end.

For example, you'd better include them in the modified version of code

```
midpoint = len(my_list)//2
longest_word(my_list[midpoint:])
longest_word(my_list[:midpoint])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there a problem with `max([len(word) for word in my_list])`? This code seems needlessly complex so solve a simple task.

Comment: List comprehension is acceptable for sure, and you need to return the word in the list based on its length, a bit like return the key based on the value in a dictionary. But the key point for my problem lies on the conversion from single to multiple recursive calls, meaning to say to "split the process" into two (half and half running simultaneously) rather than running one way through the end.

Comment: My mistake, you are right, they shouldn’t run simultaneously. But the basic idea I think use multiple recursive calls here is to find out the maximum length word in the first and second half of the list respectively, then compare them and pick the one with the higher length, instead of directly getting the result. I mean my question here is running logic now is seen more important than the results, code concision and any other aspects.

Comment: Gotcha. Since the basic solution is pretty naively direct, the additional requirements are sort of hard to comprehend and pretty confusing. I'll try a stab at the answer, and feel free to set me straight if I'm off.

Comment: Well, frankly speaking it is one bonus question from my computing assignments, whose code will run and get tested on a certain platform to check whether the intended output result and running patterns both meet the requirements (they set a series of tests to run to test your code), I failed many times of attempts, that is the reason why I am eager to seek help. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is pretty contrived (but not without merit). A simple solution is:

```
longest = max(len(x) for x in words)
longest_word = [x for x in words if longest == len(x)]
print(longest_word, longest)
```

Running time is linear (two passes), and you could easily do it in one by avoiding list comprehensions and writing a `for` loop.

However, since you are required to use multiple recursive calls, you can take a [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) approach as you mentioned:

```
def longest_word(lst):

    # base cases
    if not lst:
        return ""
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]

    # recursive case
    mid = len(lst) // 2
    a = longest_word(lst[:mid])
    b = longest_word(lst[mid:])
    return a if len(a) > len(b) else b

words = ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "rabbit", "fox"]
print(longest_word(words))
```

Slicing here is not optimal (although it does make the code succinct); using left and right indices would be more performant (an exercise for the reader). Feel free to index into the tuple to pick the word or length in the caller.

As for the strategy that's being employed, think of it as a tournament where two words battle in each bracket to determine which is longer. The longer word of the two moves up the tree to the next round.

```
       [dog vs rabbit]                  <- round 4
         |         |  
[cat vs dog]  [mouse vs rabbit]         <- round 3
  |      |       |         |
[cat]  [dog]  [mouse]  [rabbit vs fox]  <- round 2
                           |       |
                       [rabbit]  [fox]  <- round 1
```

Time complexity is O(n log(n)) because for each recursive call, we cut the list in half (similar to [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)). Another way of thinking about it is that half of the contestants are eliminated by their opponents in each round of the tournament (or each level of the call tree).

Comment: Very appreciated for your clear explanation and flow charts which show the thoughts needed to be taken step by step and term clarification as well! I know this example does seem contrived because it is obvious recursive functions are not the good way of solving such type of issue instead of using list comprehension or simple for loops. This example is just designed to familiarise learners with the using of multiple recursive calls, meaning to say the emphasis is put on functionality and logic of function execution here instead of code concision and user-friendliness.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. Divide and conquer is useful/optimal for some actual problems, so hopefully you'll get a chance to work on some of those soon (merge sort, quicksort, quickselect, etc). Let me know if there's anything else I can help with here.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I am pretty sure I will meet all of them in my further study.

Comment: By the way, if the answer resolves the problem, it's customary to accept the solution.

Comment: No problem! Sorry mate, since I am a newcomer here so I am not really familar with all those functions of the board. Hopefully I could be able to gradually familarise myself with how this site works. I took a few days off from programming so I didn't pay a visit here for a while.

Comment: No sweat! Welcome to SO.